# show content and hide all other related objects

Tags: jquery, html

So i have this switch function that i'm struggeling with.
But for some reason the menu is disappearing as soon as i click a menu-option. The only solution so far is that i encapsulate the "contents" in a new div. jsfiddle of working and non-working version: https://jsfiddle.net/yf62w1bp/1

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.menu2").click(function() {
        var clicked = $(this).attr('title');
        $("#"+clicked).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Non-working HTML:

```
<div id="menu2">
    <a href="#" title="content_1" class="menu2">menu test1</a>
    <a href="#" title="content_2" class="menu2">menu test2</a>
</div>
<div id="content_1"><p>content test1</p></div>
<div id="content_2"><p>content test2</p></div>
```

Working HTML:

```
<div id="menu2">
    <a href="#" title="content_1" class="menu2">menu test1</a>
    <a href="#" title="content_2" class="menu2">menu test2</a>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="content_1"><p>content test1</p></div>
    <div id="content_2"><p>content test2</p></div>
</div>
```

explanation to why this is occurring?

How would i modify my JS in order for it to work for the `first` solution in the JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `$.siblings()` is what's hiding the menu, because `#menu2` is a sibling of `#content_1` and `#content_2`. By nesting `#content_1` and `#content_2` in their own element, they're only siblings of one another, so it all works as intended.

If you want to retain the structure where `#menu2` is a sibling of `#content_1` and `#content_2`, then use some other method to group the elements you want to hide. Here I've given all of the toggle-able divs a class of `.toggle` and hide those instead, then show the one that matches the title you clicked on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.menu2").click(function() {
    var clicked = '#' + $(this).attr('title');
    $('.toggle:not('+clicked+')').hide(1000);
    $(clicked).show(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu2">
  <a href="#" title="content_1" class="menu2">menu test1</a>
  <a href="#" title="content_2" class="menu2">menu test2</a>
</div>
<div id="content_1" class="toggle">
  <p>content test1</p>
</div>
<div id="content_2" class="toggle">
  <p>content test2</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could still use `$.siblings()` and just use `:not()` to exclude `#menu2` from being added to the object as a sibling. But if you do this, if you introduce any other siblings later that you don't want to hide in the same way, you will need to add those elements to the selector list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.menu2").click(function() {
    var clicked = '#' + $(this).attr('title');
    $(clicked).show(1000).siblings(':not(#menu2)').hide(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu2">
  <a href="#" title="content_1" class="menu2">menu test1</a>
  <a href="#" title="content_2" class="menu2">menu test2</a>
</div>
<div id="content_1">
  <p>content test1</p>
</div>
<div id="content_2">
  <p>content test2</p>
</div>
```